# Mutual independence when rolling a sequence of dice

Tags: probability, independence, dice

Suppose we are rolling say 5 symmetrical dice, one after another, and we assume uniform distribution of probability, i.e. for each event $u$ of the form $u = (a, b, c, d, e)$, where $a,b,c,d,e$ are numbers from $1$ to $6$, we let  $P(u) = 1/6^5$. Is it then true that the collection of every set of every possible die roll at every place in the sequence is mutually independent? In other words, is it true that the set $\{A_{11}, A_{12}, \dots, A_{55}, A_{56}\}$ is mutually independent, where $A_{ij} = \{j\;\text{pips on roll number}\;i\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because $\Pr(A_{ij}\cap A_{ik})=0\neq\Pr(A_{ij})\Pr(A_{ik})$ whenever $j\neq k$. Any set which does not include any pair of this form is mutually independent: the roll on each die is independent of anything that happens on any combination of the other dice.

Comment: Thank you. Does it follow that similar sets including one or more complements are also mutually independent? For example the set $\{A_{11}, A_{21}, A_{31}, A_{41}, A_{51}^c\}$, which could be used to calculate the probability of rolling a 1 on each die except for the last one.

Comment: @SimonSMN yes, so long as each event in your set only depends on one die, and each one corresponds to a different die, they are mutually independent and you can just multiply probabilities.